# Reading Stream: Byte[] vs Memory<Byte> vs Span<Byte>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

What are the fundamental differences between:

```
var buffer = new byte[8192];
var bytesRead = Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

```
var buffer = new byte[8192];
var span = new Span<byte>(buffer);
var bytesRead = Stream.Read(span);
```

```
var buffer = new byte[8192];
var memory = new Memory<byte>(buffer);
var bytesRead = Stream.ReadAsync(memory).Result;
```

Excluding the obvious fact that they are all different object types and that the only `Stream.Read()` method that accepts a `Memory<Byte>` is `ReadAsync()` of course.

Why would I pick any of `byte[]`, `Span<byte>` or `Memory<byte>` over the others and how would I decide what is best for my situation?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/memory-and-spans/memory-t-usage-guidelines

Comment: @Julian thx for the link, but had already gone through that document, still not fully clear what the differences are and when to use one or the other. Especially because the document just focuses on abstract implementations (`Span<T>` and `Memory<T>`), no real use cases or comparison to `byte[]` in this case.

Comment: You'd pick the one you need. Ie. If you have a byte array you'd use the byte array version, whereas if you had a Memory/Span you'd use that one. Of course there's also implicit conversions to Span from arrays and most byte array methods just forwards to the Span ones these days. If you're designing an API, you'd use an abstraction such as Memory or Span so as to give your callers a choice. A span could be zero allocations, a wrapper around unmanaged memory or something else. While a byte array is always just a byte array (and usually an allocation unless using Array pool)

Comment: It is your other code that uses the received bytes that determines which approach is better, so I don't think the question in its current form can lead to some meaningful discussion.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I was hoping there would be a **single type** that abstracts over `IntPtr`, _and_ `byte*`, _and_ `Memory<Byte>` _and_ `Span<Byte>` _and_ `Byte[]` and everything else in-between (like `ArraySegment<Byte>`, `IList<Byte>`, `IReadOnlyList<Byte>`, etc) and so on... _le sigh_

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this question is about Memory/Span/array and not Read/ReadAsync,  there is no fundamental difference in this example.

The difference is that Memory/Span is an abstraction of memory, kind of like a safe pointer. They may represent a regular c# array, but might as well represent unmanaged memory. They might also represent memory of another type. So if some code loads data into a byte-array you can convert it to a int-array without doing a bunch of copying. It also supports slicing if you do not want the method to have access to all of the data.

The difference between Memory and Span is mostly that Span is more efficient, but has some restrictions in how it can be used.

So use whatever fits the data you have. If you are designing an API it is usually a good idea to take the most general type, i.e. Span/ReadonlySpan, and perhaps add overloads or extension methods for convenience.

Comment: Indeed the docs say Memory can point to unmanaged, and yet there is no constructor to allow for it in Net 6.0. Truly an abstraction.